# I want to retrieve SUM using key of JSON field in MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-json

I want to get the summation of `vehicle_rent`, `material_amount`, `other_amount`, `labour_amount`, `pa_amount` and `ta_amount` from JSON type data field using MySQL `json_extract` and `json_object` or any other `json` related methods of MySQL.

```
{
    "task_vehicle": [
        {
            "vehicle_note": "Anonymous Proof",
            "vehicle_rent": "2000"
        }
    ],
    "task_material": [
        {
            "material_note": "Anonymous Proof",
            "material_amount": 200
        }
    ],
    "task_regular_amount": {
        "other": {
            "other_amount": "250"
        },
        "labour": {
            "labour_amount": "250"
        }
    },
    "task_purchase_breakdown": [
        {
            "pa_amount": "200"
        },
        {
            "pa_amount": "200"
        }
    ],
    "task_transport_breakdown": [
        {
            "ta_amount": "250",
            "transport_type": "Bus",
        }
    ]
}
```

I am able to extract and sum the values if json data is straight forward as follows-

```
{
"vehicle_rent": "2000",
"material_amount": "200",
"other_amount": "250".
"ta_amount": "250"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The order can't be influneced.

> ```
> SELECT JSON_OBJECT('vehicle_rent',JSON_EXTRACT('{
>     "task_vehicle": [
>         {
>             "vehicle_note": "Anonymous Proof",
>             "vehicle_rent": "2000"
>         }
>     ],
>     "task_material": [
>         {
>             "material_note": "Anonymous Proof",
>             "material_amount": 200
>         }
>     ],
>     "task_regular_amount": {
>         "other": {
>             "other_amount": "250"
>         },
>         "labour": {
>             "labour_amount": "250"
>         }
>     },
>     "task_purchase_breakdown": [
>         {
>             "pa_amount": "200"
>         },
>         {
>             "pa_amount": "200"
>         }
>     ],
>     "task_transport_breakdown": [
>         {
>             "ta_amount": "250",
>             "transport_type": "Bus"
>         }
>     ]
> }'
> , '$.task_vehicle[0].vehicle_rent'),'material_amount',
> JSON_EXTRACT('{
>     "task_vehicle": [
>         {
>             "vehicle_note": "Anonymous Proof",
>             "vehicle_rent": "2000"
>         }
>     ],
>     "task_material": [
>         {
>             "material_note": "Anonymous Proof",
>             "material_amount": 200
>         }
>     ],
>     "task_regular_amount": {
>         "other": {
>             "other_amount": "250"
>         },
>         "labour": {
>             "labour_amount": "250"
>         }
>     },
>     "task_purchase_breakdown": [
>         {
>             "pa_amount": "200"
>         },
>         {
>             "pa_amount": "200"
>         }
>     ],
>     "task_transport_breakdown": [
>         {
>             "ta_amount": "250",
>             "transport_type": "Bus"
>         }
>     ]
> }'
> , '$.task_material[0].material_amount')
> ,'other_amount',
> JSON_EXTRACT('{
>     "task_vehicle": [
>         {
>             "vehicle_note": "Anonymous Proof",
>             "vehicle_rent": "2000"
>         }
>     ],
>     "task_material": [
>         {
>             "material_note": "Anonymous Proof",
>             "material_amount": 200
>         }
>     ],
>     "task_regular_amount": {
>         "other": {
>             "other_amount": "250"
>         },
>         "labour": {
>             "labour_amount": "250"
>         }
>     },
>     "task_purchase_breakdown": [
>         {
>             "pa_amount": "200"
>         },
>         {
>             "pa_amount": "200"
>         }
>     ],
>     "task_transport_breakdown": [
>         {
>             "ta_amount": "250",
>             "transport_type": "Bus"
>         }
>     ]
> }'
> , '$.task_regular_amount.other.other_amount'),'ta_amount',
> JSON_EXTRACT('{
>     "task_vehicle": [
>         {
>             "vehicle_note": "Anonymous Proof",
>             "vehicle_rent": "2000"
>         }
>     ],
>     "task_material": [
>         {
>             "material_note": "Anonymous Proof",
>             "material_amount": 200
>         }
>     ],
>     "task_regular_amount": {
>         "other": {
>             "other_amount": "250"
>         },
>         "labour": {
>             "labour_amount": "250"
>         }
>     },
>     "task_purchase_breakdown": [
>         {
>             "pa_amount": "200"
>         },
>         {
>             "pa_amount": "200"
>         }
>     ],
>     "task_transport_breakdown": [
>         {
>             "ta_amount": "250",
>             "transport_type": "Bus"
>         }
>     ]
> }'
> , '$.task_transport_breakdown[0].ta_amount')) as result
> ```
>
> ```
> | result                                                                                      |
> | :------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ |
> | {"ta_amount": "250", "other_amount": "250", "vehicle_rent": "2000", "material_amount": 200} |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=8b7f4714f9a840a685d44a2a986a0741)*

Comment: Thanks for your help though. It helps me a lot to understand the query and given way to think. Loved it <3.